# Youtube data APIのクォーター申請について

Tags: youtube

Youtube data APIのクォーター申請について、
試しに既存に存在するサービスと同じプログラムを作って申請をしたところ、
なぜか、ポリシー違反だとして許可されませんでした。

Policy  I.16 (Additional Prohibitions)

画面構成や機能も全く同じなので、
そういう意味では、違反はないはずなのですが、
理由は上記のポリシー違反としか説明がされずに、
何が違反なのかわからない形です

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#i.-additional-prohibitions

ポリシーの中身も読みましたが、特別問題があるとも思えず、
そもそも他社のサービスがそれで普通にアプリが使えてるので、
違反とされわけがないと思ってます。

これもっと具体的に教えてくれるところはないのでしょうか？

ちなみに日本のサービスはkamuitracerというサービスです。
これと同じことをしたいわけではないのですが、
API申請時にこのままやったら落とされたので、原因が知りたいのです。

また、このクォーターの申請ついて、なるべくポリシーにきちんと準拠するために、
具体的なアドバイスなどもらえるようなサポートはないのでしょうか？
申請時のコメントは具体性に欠けており、何が原因か説明なく、
さらに言えば、他でできてるのに、申請だとダメという謎な審査をされてるので、
もっと詳しいこと教えてくれるサポートが欲しいです

Comment: 一部Googleに対する要望も入っているかな？とおもいますのでこちらをご覧になったほうがよろしいかと思います。[製品やライブラリの公式サイトからこのサイトを訪れた方へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2111/)

Answer (score 2):

こういうのはだいたい具体的な理由は教えてくれないものなので自分で調べるか知識がある人に頼むしかないのですが、スマートフォンのアプリの申請代行というのはあるようですが、APIのクオータ増量のリジェクト理由調査や申請代行というのはニッチすぎて専門のサービスとしては存在しないんじゃないでしょうか。

- Youtubeを使ったWebサービスの開発実績がある会社を探す
- クラウドソーシングかなんかで経験者にお願いする

でしょうか。

ところで気になったのは「他社サービスのクローンを作ってダミーで申請した」という事実とそれを当然かのように公言されている点です。申請自体が悪意があると判断されかねませんし、第三者的にも「自分は正当であり審査が誤っている」という主張も素直に受け入れがたいところがあります。そういう点でも、誰か別の人と一緒に(特定の事項だけを依頼するのではなく)やられたほうがいいのではないでしょうか。